# Return key for fuzzy search of value with underscore

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I'm trying to return a key given an approximate match of the value.
Here is my dictionary data

```
const dict = {
    "key": "value",
    "nova": "nov",
    "euro": "eur"
}
```

Instead of looping through is there an easier way to do this with underscore or vanilla js? Basically, if the input string has any substring match from the "key" then return the "value".

Examples

```
input: "nova_w2" output: "nov"
input: "nova_2323" output: "nov"
input: "novae" output: "nov"
input: "euro12" output: "eur"
```

Comment: Could you be  more specific about what you want to achieve?

Comment: Looks like you want to put all the mapped values into a query-able form, then run some sort of Levenshtein distance [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance] query against them, returning the key/value with the smallest distance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't really do this without looping if you have to check the entire dictionary.
But it's quite simple. Loop over the dictionary. If the word incldues the key, return the value.

```js
const dict = {
    "key": "value",
    "nova": "nov",
    "euro": "eur"
};
const lookup = word => {
  const match = Object.entries( dict ).find(([ key, value ]) => word.includes( key ));
  return match
    ? match[ 1 ]
    : false;
};
console.log( lookup( 'nova_w2' ));
console.log( lookup( 'nova_2323' ));
console.log( lookup( 'novae' ));
console.log( lookup( 'euro12' ));
console.log( lookup( 'thisShouldNotBeFound' ));
```

Answer (score 0):

We can search the object for the proper key using `Object.keys()`, then using find we can find which one matches.

```
let key = Object.keys(dict).find(key => this.value.includes(key))
```

Here is a working example:

```js
const dict = {
  "key": "value",
  "nova": "nov",
  "euro": "eur"
}

const input = document.querySelector('input')
input.addEventListener('input', function() {
  let key = Object.keys(dict).find(key => this.value.includes(key))
  console.log(dict[key])
})
```

```html
<input type="text">
```